# Dependency issue trying to install php-mbstring on ec2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, dependencies, yii2, mbstring

I am trying to install `yii2` on my Amazon Linux AMI instance, it requires the `php-mbstring` extension to work.

When I tried to run `sudo yum install php-mbstring` it returned this error:

> Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
2494 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.9-1.112.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: 5.5 and 5.3?... And 5.6?  Can you not find packages with matching versions?

Comment: On Amazon Linux, PHP versions from 5.4 and on are set up to run side by side. Use alternatives to set the active version.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It seems you have php 5.6 installed.
You need to install `mbstring` for that particular version of `php`.

Run `sudo yum install php56-mbstring`

After that it might be a good idea to restart apache (thanks! [@hexicle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333621/hexicle)),
using `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: other commands that might help.  `yum search`, `yum list installed`, `man yum`.

Comment: I had to restart the server for mbstring to kick in. `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: And if you are on PHP 7 `sudo yum install php70-mbstring`

Comment: And if you are on PHP 7.2 `sudo yum install php72-mbstring`

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09

```
sudo yum install php70-mysqlnd
sudo service httpd restart
```