# installing laravel on EC2 - mbstring issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5.2 successfully on my Mac machine. But now I am walking through the procedures to install Laravel on AWS.

Once I got the instance running, I installed apache, php and mysql with the following command:
*sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd*

The php version is 5.6.17

I then did the following:

*composer global require "laravel/installer"*

and updated the path: export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin

when I navigate to /var/www/html and do "laravel new ", the project gets created but I receive an mbstring extension problem.  Below is a text dump of what I saw:

```
laravel new hws3
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of    packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/framework v5.2.29 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.29].
- laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

I've scoured the internet and only found a solution for Windows. I am using Amazon Linux. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you install composet before installing laravel?

Comment: Hi ggderas, I did install composer with the following commands:    

    sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
    sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have php 5.6 installed.
You need to install mbstring for that particular version of php.

Run `sudo yum install php56-mbstring`

credits: [Alex Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043552/alex-andrei) answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190547/dependency-issue-trying-to-install-php-mbstring-on-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Laravel with composer, This is the right answer!

```
sudo su //to be root
yum install php56-mbstring
```